# Adjust Microphone Recording Volume

Tags: android, volume, microphone

We are trying to adjust the volume level at which we record.  It seems like the microphone is very sensitive and picks up a lot of static.

We looked at setVolumeControlStream, but could not find a stream to pass into it to control the microphone.

Answer (score 2):

Set your audio source as *'MIC'* using *[MediaRecorder.AudioSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html)* class and adjust volume by calling *[onVolumeSetRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRouter.VolumeCallback.html)* method.

Comment: Can anyone verify this works? I'm not currently working with this project any more.

Comment: I can't see what object you would call this callback on, so the answer doesn't make sense to me.  Would be great if you can clarify.