# How to adjust microphone volume in Android programmatically

Tags: android, audio-recording

Is there a way to increase/decrease the input volume of the Android microphone. I did some research on Google as well as StackOverflow but didn't find a suitable answer.
Here are some links:

[How to adjust microphone volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175902/how-to-adjust-microphone-volume-in-android)

[Adjust Microphone Recording Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994683/adjust-microphone-recording-volume)

[Is Android capable of managing microphone/input volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949347/is-android-capable-of-managing-microphone-input-volume).

Please provide any help/reference.

Answer (score 3):

I had a certain problem where I had to increase the volume (gain) of the sound and also filter out some frequencies I used [TarsosDSP library for android](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) it has a particular class called GainProcessor where you can adjust the sound accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks It seems a good option.Can u please provide any assistance in importing this library into eclipse.

Comment: https://github.com/srubin/TarsosDSP/releases/tag/TarsosDSPAndroid-v3-MAD this link has a jar file version of the lib that you can import like a normal jar in your eclipse project